# Limit CSS animation per session

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, nopcommerce

My website currently has an SVG Logo in the header which animates using CSS on load. 
I would really like to limit this animation to once per **session**.

I understand how to limit the animation to loop only once, however whenever the user navigates to a new page, it again animates once on page load. 
The goal would be to get the animation to play once, then not animate again regardless which pages the user navigates to.

I'm open to suggestions on how to make this happen.

The website is built on the NOP Commerce system, using a custom Web to print plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible using only CSS. Animation will fire when the CSS is rendered. You would probably need to base it on a PHP/Javascript session

Comment: Maybe use Javascript to load the CSS and write a cookie at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This will require some logic, either serverside or with some Javascript.

Below is an example of a working javascript based solution. The logo has an ID of `logo`, and the animation only targets the logo if it also has the class `animate`.

Javascript checks to see if a [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) variable is set. If it's not, the class is added to the logo, and the sessionStorage variable is set so it won't run again.

Note: The example won't run on Stackoverflow but should work in real life.

```js
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('logoAnimated') === null) {
  document.getElementById("logo").classList.add('animate');
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('logoAnimated', 1);
}
```

```css
@keyframes logoAnimation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#logo.animate {
  animation: logoAnimation 1s;
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="">
```